# How toxic is zinc sulfate for moss control?

Tags: pesticide, moss

I live in Portland, Oregon and I'm battling moss on my asphalt shingle roof. I usually scrub it off manually, but it's extra bad this year and I might need more help than my broom.

My neighbor swears by [Moss B Ware](https://www.mossout.com/all-products/corrys-moss-b-ware-shaker) which is zinc sulfate. I don't know anything about this chemical and before I sprinkle it all over my roof, I want to understand just how toxic and/or creepy it is. I only use organic products in my garden. Is it responsible to use this chemical on my roof/yard? If not, can you recommend something better?

Comment: Is the roof flat or pent (sloping)?

Comment: The material safety data sheet doesn't say much, it appears dust is the most hazardous thing if you breath it in a lot..https://www.pure-chemical.com/msds/Zinc%20sulfate.pdf

Comment: The roof is pitched but gentle. I can walk in it easily.

Answer (score 1):

A quick google search on Zinc Sulfate yielded [this interesting page.](http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/znso4gen.html#:%7E:text=Can%20zinc%20sulfate%20affect%20birds,to%20freshwater%20fish%20and%20invertebrates.)

Briefly, it's fairly innocuous in an of itself, but like many inorganic salts, too much can have environmental effects. If you have runoff into waterways, it's toxic to aquatic fauna. I don't know how much you have to use to control moss. Use according to label and you're *probably* okay.

From the website:

> What happens to zinc sulfate in the environment? Zinc naturally occurs
> in the environment. It can be found in animals, plants, and soil. Zinc
> may come from natural sources, pesticides, or human activities such as
> farming, and the production of batteries, animal feed, and metals.
> Zinc is also used as a food additive.
>
> Zinc sulfate is an inorganic salt that dissolves in water to form zinc
> ions. The formation of zinc ions depends on water pH and the presence
> of agents that can bind and capture zinc. Solubility makes zinc
> available to plants and other organisms in soil; that availability
> depends on soil pH. Zinc in the environment is considered immobile
> because different substances bind to it.
>
> Can zinc sulfate affect birds, fish, or other wildlife? Zinc salts are
> slightly toxic or practically non-toxic to birds and highly toxic to
> freshwater fish and invertebrates. No data were available on toxicity
> to bees. Bees and other pollinators are not likely to be harmed
> because they do not eat much plant material.

Comment: I found that fact sheet, too. But I found it frustratingly inconclusive. I was hoping there might be consensus from responsible gardeners about whether it's responsible to use this product on a roof. Does it contaminate ground water? Will it kill other plants or insects in my yard? I never use products like Round-Up to kill weeds. Is this in that category?

Comment: Not in the same category as glyphosate, an organic compound. Think of zinc sulfate like you would table salt. A little bit is fine, even necessary. Too much can cause problems. I seriously doubt it would harm any plants or insects in your yard, used according to label. I don't know enough about it to comment on the groundwater question.